# Use OR condition in graphql query for gatsby-transformer-remark

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to use graphql to return a node if one of three fields match but can't get the OR condition working. I've got as far as below but receive `Field "OR" is not defined by type MarkdownRemarkFieldsFilterInput`

I've done a fair bit of searching but couldn't find much information on `markdownRemark`. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    markdownRemark(
      fields: {
        OR: [
          { slug: { eq: $slug } }
          { en_slug: { eq: $slug } }
          { de_slug: { eq: $slug } }
        ]
      }
    ) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: if not available in playground then not supported

Comment: Are you only expecting one of them to be present?

Comment: I'm expecting all three to be present and have values (these are set when the node is created). `$slug` here should be the browser url (?) and so i want to match the same node for all three possible $slugs `...com/de/page`  `...com/en/page` and `...com/page`. Please forgive me if i've completely misunderstood gatsby so far, i'm just learning and here I'm trying to bypass having to create separate lang specific files.